# Update post meta before sending wp_mail

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some custom fields that update using `update_post_meta()`. I also use a wp_mail function to send out an email on publish that is meant to include all the post meta that the user has just entered. However, after hours of trying to figure out why the custom fields where never included in the mail template, it turns out if i hit update, the mail goes out again with all the data. So im guessing that `wp_mail()` is firing before `update_post_meta()`.

Any ideas.

Comment: You could always put an `error_log` in the `update_post_meta` method and a `die` in `wp_mail` and tail the logs and make sure you see the `error_log` entry before the script dies. That would confirm your codepath at least.

Comment: I dont really follow how this would help. Excuse my ignorance, lack of experience with error logs. 
Is there any way I can set the order of these functions?

Comment: Put this in `update_post_meta`: `error_log('In the upm method');` and then put this in `wp_mail`: `die('in wp mail`);`